# SQL: Counting number of occurances over multiple columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Cannot get my head around the SQL that will return the number of times a user has accessed a particular service. Think it might require a nested count and select, but cannot get my head around it.

The data looks like this:

```
UserID  Service
---------------
1       Map1
1       Map2
1       Map1
2       Map1
2       Map2
3       Map4
3       Map2
3       Map2
3       Map2
...     ...
```

And the desired kind of output is something along the lines of this:

```
UserID  Service  TimesAccessed
------------------------------
1       Map1     2
1       Map2     1
2       Map1     1     
2       Map2     1
3       Map3     3
3       Map4     1
...     ...      ...
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
SELECT  UserID, Service, COUNT(UserID) TimesAccessed
FROM    Table
GROUP BY UserID, Service
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
select  
    userid, service, count(userid)  
 from   
    table  
 group by  
    userid, service
```

Comment: No problem, glad we could help.

Comment: Sorry, think you actually pipped me by a split second as well!

Comment: It's fine, this once, don't do it again. Your answer was better formatted and complete though.